# Merge the [android-l] and [android-5.0-lollipop] tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

Android 5.0 Lollipop was just introduced yesterday. Before this, it was called Android L. Since it now has a name, could [android-l](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-l) be merged and synonymized into [android-5.0-lollipop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-5.0-lollipop)? This is the tag naming scheme that we've [been using recently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-4.4-kitkat).

Comment: yes please do. go ahead :). /me agree